# Dump content of TCustomActionList descendant into human-readable form

Tags: delphi

I have foreign object instance and i want to examine properties of the component "manually". 
I know about component streaming and how to convert output to text format, but problem is - TCustomActionList (as i figured out my instance is TActionManager) wont stream its actions. Is there any trick to have it to do so?

---

UPD: Now doing that by creating TDataModule (as container/owner), iterating thru Actions and creating TAction instances and doing Assign. Solution still suffers from not caring about TAction descendants tho.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm guessing that the downvoter didn't like that you didn't show your code.  By the way, creating a data module to iterate an object is completely unecessary, so I have no idea what kind of code you would have written.

Comment: @Warren P, re: downvote - i know who did and why, have no problem about it (its personal, like sending XOXO in other social networks); re: code - now i agree, solution might be found faster in this case, since now i figured out what i had a specific misconception; re: TDataModule - my misconception was to write **all of the actions** and then convert them by ObjectBinaryToText which doesnt liked it (wants container, otherwise stops after single action). Now i have complete dump, thanks to your fresh look at the problem.

Comment: +1 from me as well. Nicely stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example that doesn't do anything tricky.

```
function  TMyThing.SaveComponent(a:TComponent):String;
var
  Stream2: TStringStream;
  Stream1: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream2 := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Stream1.WriteComponent(a);
    Stream1.position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(Stream1, Stream2);
    result := Stream2.DataString;
  finally
    Stream1.Free;
    Stream2.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThing.Dump;
var
 n:Integer;
 a:TContainedAction;
 s:String;
begin
  for n := 0 to ActionManager1.ActionCount-1 do begin
      a := ActionManager1.Actions[n];
      s := '----- '+a.Category+' '+a.Name+' '+a.ClassName+':';
      // crude manual way
      if a is TAction then begin
          s := s+ ' '+TAction(a).Caption;
          s := s+ ' '+TAction(a).Hint;

      end;
      // RTTI stream in DFM text format
      s := s+ SaveComponent(a);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is kinda crude; Hint, ImageIndex, ShortCut are missing, but can be added. Worse - any property which might be defined by descendant action class will never be reflected this way.

Comment: check it out. Much better now.

Comment: Indeed, actually it works around my issue with ObjectBinaryToText (it comes i had a severe misconception about the way it work (container))